# Why is Xcode needed for running Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode

When we set up the appropriate environment for running Ruby on Rails, we need to install x-code. I also did it but don't know how it works and why we need to install it.

Could you give me some answers?

Answer (score 3):

There are some modules for ruby, that are written for performance reasons in a mixture of C++ and Ruby code.

To install them, they need to be compiled first - and for that, you'll need the system compiler.

Comment: The compiler, but not the IDE. Strictly speaking, Xcode is not needed, only the `g++` or `clang++` compilers.

Comment: I don't think Apple packages their official clang++ compiler without the rest of x-code - so you end up with the IDE as well.

Comment: `Command Likes Tools` must have it. It's released by Apple. It can be installed without XCode and I think that's the point.